# Why is my footer not pressed to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, web, layout

Why is my footer not pressed to the bottom?

```
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header">Header</header>
    <main class="main">Main</main>
    <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: If you change min-height % to vh then it works. Why is that?

I don't understand why it works like that.

Comment: Hello Nazar, and welcome to Stackoverflow, I wanted to edit your post to remove the extra ticks (started on your code and finished in the last html too ), but I could not , I dunno why. By the way to fix your code , you just have to replace your selected style `body {height: 100%;}` by `html, body {height: 100%}` it would work. 
look at [this exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/vh7ad0z9/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the use of min-height property set to 100%. This is telling the browser to set the minimum height of the wrapper div to be 100% of the viewport height, but since the main and header elements are also set to take up space, the footer is pushed down below the fold.

On the other hand, if you change min-height to vh, it works because vh (viewport height) is a unit of measurement that is relative to the height of the viewport and not the parent element. Therefore, it correctly sets the height of the wrapper div to be the full height of the viewport, and since the main and header elements have a flex: 1 1 auto property, they are taking up all the available space and the footer is at the bottom of the viewport.